# Preselect <select> value, data-src

Tags: php, jquery, select, datatable

I'm have built a DataTable table with an edit button that opens up a bootstrap modal to edit the record. I used the answer from Yevgen Gorbunkov here : [Edit DataTables source data, using form inside pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824899/edit-datatables-source-data-using-form-inside-pop-up-window?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Btw if you happen to read this thread, thank you for this solution!

I can get inputs and textareas to prefill with data but I have stumbled with select values. I can see that it selects a right value but it doesnt appear as selected when I open up the form.(https://www.upload.ee/image/11198680/probleem.PNG). Notice the little tick on the right.

I think that the problem is that my select options doesnt have selected value but I don't know how to add it? Can someone help me or point out the way to solution?

My select tag:

```
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="VaruosaSeotudBIDMuuda" name="VaruosaSeotudBIDMuuda" style="width: 100%;" data-src="VaruosaSeotudBID">
<option></option>
<?php 
include ("config.php");
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT varuosad.VaruosaID, varuosad.VaruosaNimetus, varuosad.VaruosaKood from varuosad");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
echo "<option value=" . $row['VaruosaID'] . ">" . $row['VaruosaNimetus'] . ' / '. $row['VaruosaKood'] . "</option>";
}
?>


</select>
```

Getting the row info from datatable

```
                        //edit row handler
        table.on('click', '.edit', function(){
    //get clicked row
    const rowClicked = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
    //populate edit form with row data by corresponding 
    //rowClicked property based on 'data-src' attribute
     $.each($('#MuudaSeotudToodeForm input,textarea,select'), function(){
      $(this).val(rowClicked.data()[$(this).attr('data-src')]);

    });
    //$('#VaruosaSeotudBIDMuuda').val('3');

    //set modal attribute rowindex to corresponding row index
    $('#MuudaSeotudToodeForm').attr('rowindex', rowClicked.index());
    //open up edit form modal
    $('#SeotudToodeMuudaModal').modal('toggle');
  });




         //submit edits handler
  $('#SeotudToodeMuudaModal').on('click', '#MuudaSeotudToodeBTN', function(){
    //grab modified data into object
    const modifiedData = {};
    $.each($('#MuudaSeotudToodeForm input,textarea,select'), function(){
      Object.assign(modifiedData, {[$(this).attr('data-src')]:$(this).val()});

    });
    //send modified data to the backend
    $.ajax({
      url: 'pages/varuosakataloog/varuosakataloogMuudaSeotudToode.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {id: $('#MuudaSeotudToodeForm').attr('rowindex'), ...modifiedData},
      success: () => {
        //close the modal
        $('#SeotudToodeMuudaModal').modal('hide');
        //re-draw datatable
        table.ajax.reload();
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Got help here.

[bootstrap-select nothing selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768332/bootstrap-select-nothing-selected)

Adding this solved my problem :

```
$('#VaruosaSeotudBIDMuuda').selectpicker('refresh');
```

full code if any beginner finds his way here :

```
//edit row handler
        table.on('click', '.edit', function(){
    //get clicked row
    const rowClicked = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
    //populate edit form with row data by corresponding 
    //rowClicked property based on 'data-src' attribute
     $.each($('#MuudaSeotudToodeForm input,textarea,select'), function(){
      $(this).val(rowClicked.data()[$(this).attr('data-src')]);

    });
    $('#VaruosaSeotudBIDMuuda').selectpicker('refresh');

    //set modal attribute rowindex to corresponding row index
    $('#MuudaSeotudToodeForm').attr('rowindex', rowClicked.index());
    //open up edit form modal
    $('#SeotudToodeMuudaModal').modal('toggle');
  });
```